# Executing a Python Script From Python Shell

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to access the Amazon Advertising through Python and I created a Python script to automate the authentication process.  This file, called amazon.py is located in ~/PROJECT/APP/amazon.py.

I want to be able to play around with the API, so I launched python manage.py shell from the ~/PROJECT directory to enter the Python shell.  My goal is to be able to execute the python script amazon.py within this shell.  What command should I be using to execute amazon.py?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you just import the file and call a function within it:

```
import APP.amazon
APP.amazon.main()
```

This would only work if amazon.py is laid out like this:

```
def main():
    ...code...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, in the directory ~/PROJECT/APP there needs to exist a file `__init__.py` with nothing in it, or else Python won't see APP as a package with the module amazon in it.

Disclaimer: I don't actually know what manage.py does.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a script is "executed" upon import. I'd suggest you wrap your functionality in `amazon.py` in a function:

```
def call_functionality():
    ...
```

In your shell you can now import it with:

```
import path.to.amazon as amazon
```

and then execute it by

```
amazon.call_functionality()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped!  I ended up creating an authenticate() function in amazon.py.  In authenticate(), I declared an amazon_api object that serves to access the API.  How can I make this available to me after I execute amazon.authenticate() from the shell?  I'm guessing the reason it doesn't exist is because it's a local variable?

Comment: Nevermind, answered my own question.  I can just return the object.

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise if you save this in a module object you could still access it by `amazon.somevariable`.